# Is there a special compiler variable in iOS SDK, which identifies the configuration at compile time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

As subject says. I would like to identify the configuration (Debug, Release, whatever), which is currently set in XCode during compilation

Sort of:

```
#if Configuration
#endif
```

Does one know?

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
#ifdef DEBUG
 <whatever>
#endif
```

for wrapping logging/debugging lines. I came across this on Cocoa Is My Girlfriend's [Dropping NSLog in release builds](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/01/24/dropping-nslog-in-release-builds/) article. I haven't done it for other configurations, but I suspect that adding -DDEBUG to 'Other C Flags' may define DEBUG. If that's the case, then you should be able to do something similar for RELEASE or DISTRIBUTION.

Answer (score 0):

Another handy one is:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
```

Which is the same as saying "if I am building with SDK for iOS 4.0 or greater"...

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet will work if you add `$(CONFIGURATION)` to the Preprocessor Macros in the projects build settings.